# Trying to add nodejs and npm (or yarn) to a yocto image (poky:zeus)

Tags: node.js, yocto

I want to add nodejs and npm (or yarn) support to a new image based on core-image-base.  Existing examples no longer work or at least don't for me.  Anyone have an example of how to do it with poky/zeus?

(Target is a ARM board and I'm using Ubuntu 18 to run Yocto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find nodejs recipe [here](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/nodejs/nodejs_12.14.1.bb?h=master) and more info [here](https://github.com/imyller/meta-nodejs)

Don't forget to add the layer ( take a look to [installation process](https://github.com/imyller/meta-nodejs#installation))

So you should be able to add packages with following command:
IMAGE_INSTALL += "nodejs nodejs-npm"

Answer (score 0):

The big issue that I was having was that I kept getting various compilation errors.  I deleted meta-openembedded and cloned it again and specified the zeus branch explicitly and after that I was able to do the compile.  (I'm getting node 10 rather than node 12, but that is fine with me.)

Working great (npm too)